# Download file from secure FTP via REST

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, ftp

I'm trying to get my head around how to download a file from a secure FTP server from my AngularJS application using REST.

Thing is, that for security reasons, I can't just append an iframe or set window.location to `ftp://myip:81/myfolder/myfile.pdf`, so I have to find a way to trigger the download without this. My initial thought was to create a Generic handler which takes the filename and the folder name as parameters and then serve the file to the user through the context.Response somehow.

What I have so far is this:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(path);
request.UsePassive = false;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpHelper.Username, ftpHelper.Password);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.File.DownloadFile;

using (var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        // stuck here ...
    }
}

request.Abort();
```

I've got a feeling that this isn't possible, though ;-) Can anyone confirm/disprove? And if it can be done, I'd love a small example/hint on this :-)

Thanks!

Comment: Oh, it's definitely possible. You just have to set the correct headers, clear the default response, write the file to the response stream and end the request. However, requesting files from FTP is relatively expensive. Is it not possible for you to setup a normal web server on top of the FTP data?

Comment: I like to use GridFS from MongoDB to handle file upload/downloads. It has some advantages over using FTP.

Comment: NicolasMoise: I have to read up on MongoDB for sure :-) Looks neat! Thanks!

Comment: Luaan: have you got a code example of that? :-) For inspiration. Also, the files that users will download are less than 1 mb in size, so I guess the FtpWebRequest is alright, yes? ;-)